# Not getting 2.5A or 2 A DC current

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVXY7E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I checking the output of the circuit's current by attaching multimeter(ON 10 A) in series with a load of 3 Ohms resistor. But I am getting a 0.22mA current output.

Here's the diagram (LM338K circuit) :

[image]

This is the circuit I am trying to build:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm338.pdf on page no.12.

I connected my multimeter's red wire to capacitors (almost red color in the picture) and black to 3 Ohms resistor.

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. According to schmetic, I should already get 5V output. But I am not getting that too.

PS: Every 1.5 + 1.5 Ohms resistor I add as a load after taking out from circuit it doesn't show any resistance on multimeter.

Hi, I have not got a solution for this please help me regarding this.

If I use LM2576 12-V version to get 5.1V with 2.2A will this be fine?

Photo :
[image]

[image]

I am getting 15.68 V without Load resistor and with load resistor same voltage and this burns resistors. Please help.

Comment: What is Ckt? And more imporantly, can you add a little bit of context? What is this device for? Also, your multimeter fails to measure resistance, so why do you trust its current measurement?

Comment: Acutally My resistors are being burned down. I don't know why but till morning it was working great. And Now my Ckt is not working as usual. It is not giving me 5V constant output. I am creating this ckt to use as a power supply for my Raspberry  pi 3B+.

Comment: What is the measured output voltage of the regulator? Is the fuse in you multimeter blown?

Comment: It's adjustable output Voltage Regulator and I have mentioned above the circuit diagram from its data sheet which is page no.12.

Comment: Are you getting the voltage you expect?

Comment: No Sir, I was getting it till this morning but right now my load resistors keep getting Burned Up. so I am getting 15.98 V.

Comment: How much cooling do you have on the regulator? Sounds like the regulator is shorted from input to output.

Comment: My room temperature is 16 degree and applied liittle heatsinK to it.No I have Not shorted input to output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93908/discussion-between-peter-karlsen-and-el-dorado).

Comment: Ballpark figures you have configured this linear regulator to drop about 10V then supply about 2A. That's about 20W. This part may be specified for 5A but it still needs help to get rid of all that heat.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I have added a heatsink. I have added a LM7805 ckt also with this ckt and it is working fine.

Comment: What is the power rating of your load resistor?

Comment: I don't know that but it's 1.5 Ohms resistor and I am using 2 of them. It was working great for 4-5 days I don't why it broke today.

Comment: P = V^2 / R = 5.58^2 / 3 = 10.37 Watt. Do you really using power resistor?

Comment: I don't know I am using a normal one which I have bought in box.

Comment: That look like 1/4W resistors. That would be why they keep burning.

Comment: If I don't add Load resistors I can't draw 5.1 V right? And can't use it for my application.

Comment: I will eventually get Input Voltage of IC only.

Comment: @El_Dorado what is the IC at the upper left on your breadboard? Why you're not connecting your 16V power supply directly to the input pin of the LM338?

Comment: I am Connecting 16 Volt directly to the LM338 IC. Please look at the ceramic Capacitor side. and Upper left is an LM7805 ckt these both ckts are powered by 16V PSU. And I am not connecting LM7805 ckt with LM338.

Comment: Do you know how to compute Watts and heatsink required?  If it is too hot to touch, then it is under-designed

Comment: P = A x V and heatsink is required I know. But can you please help me solve my problem here.

Comment: Get a 20 Watt resistor around 4.4 Ohm or start over and use the proper input supply.  You destroyed some parts, start over

Comment: I have Input supply of 16V 4.5A and the IC can take it. And 4.4 Ohms 20 Watt resistor as in for Load resistor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, you're working on a **breadboard**.

Breadboards have so much contact resistance that it will be **impossible** to make your circuit work properly. You expect a couple of Ampere to flow, **that's not going to happen** in this setup.

I would only rely on a breadboard for currents up to 100mA, for higher currents the voltage drop across wires and contacts is simply too high preventing the circuit from behaving as it is designed to.

Also you're not using any **heatsink** on the voltage regulator so even **if** a high current would flow it would **heat up** and limit the current to protect itself.

Your circuit's schematic looks OK, you just need to build it on some prototype PCB (or veroboard) so that you have **soldered contacts** instead of plug-in contacts as on a solderless breadbord.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. It has an LM7805 ckt also which supplies 900mA current. This ckt was working fine till now what happened I don't know  :(

Comment: LM338K is a 5A output IC And why am I not getting required Voltage if the ckt is fine?

Comment: If I don't add Load resistors I can't draw 5.1 V right? And can't use it for my application.I will eventually get Input Voltage of IC only

Comment: From your comments I see that you are still missing the point and do not understand how things work. *I can't draw 5.1 V right?* Without load resistors you should see 5.1 V if the resistor divider is OK. **Currents** are "drawn", voltages are not. *I will eventually get Input Voltage of IC only* **No**, that's not how voltage regulators work. There is always a small load: the voltage divider. You **really** need to educate yourself more on this **or** just use ready made modules like: https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-lm2596-module.html

Comment: I was just confirming Sir. I am not getting 5.1 Voltage as an output. Please, can you check it with the datasheet ckt reference I have provided above, what are my mistakes and all?

Comment: Anyone any opinion on this?

Comment: @El_Dorado Without the load resistor do you still get any voltage on the regulator output?

Comment: Yes, I get 15.98V.

Answer (score 0):

For a 1.7A load you are dumping heat with the voltage * current drop that tries to heat up U2 to 434'C before OTP cuts in.

Not a great way to provide power, but the lossy way is to use a power resistor or light bulb up front.

Next time try to match your supply to the load, rather than drop down to 1/3rd the input for high current.

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94364/discussion-on-answer-by-sunnyskyguy-ee75-not-getting-2-5a-or-2-a-dc-current).  Any conclusions reached should be edited back into the question and/or any answer(s).